# What are the default folders in the root of a new Magento 2.2.6 install?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

May sound odd, and maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing, but I cannot find a list of the folders that should be created in a default install of 2.2.6 that is set to production, with sample data. And has static content deployed.

Looking for the root folders only. I'm fairly certain it has changed since Magento 2.0, but my search has been fruitless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how default root folder of magento 2 look like

[image]